# dropdown-textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, textbox, drop-down-menu

is there any jquery plugin which provides an dropdown-textbox functionality? 
something similar to http://lab.anotherdan.com/js/textdropdownlist/
In this example he is making use of ul and li items.. but can the same be done for `<options>`?
i am not sure if what i am asking is even possible. so any suggestions regarding this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

check it out jquery ui library:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

cheers